# Symfony 4 api - how do I update an entity

Tags: json, rest, api, symfony

I have created a `Symfony 4` project which uses `jms_serializer` `annotations` and `fos_rest_bundle`

I am wondering how I would go about updating an existing entity.

I have the following:

```
class ProgramController extends FOSRestController {

 /**
  * @FOSRest\Put("/programs/{id}")
  * @ParamConverter("updatedProgram", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
  */
  public function putProgram(Program $program, Program $updatedProgram) 
  {
     //missing logic here
  }
}
```

Using `ParamConverters` I have 2 `Program Entity Objects`
`$program` - which is populated from the database
`$updatedProgram` - which is populated from the submitted `json` data

`Program Entities` have multiple relations to other `Entities`.

What is the best way to update the program?

Do I simply overwrite `$program` with `$updatedProgram`? (This would assume that all of the existing `$program` data is part of `$updatedProgram` and not just the updates.

Do I need to manually set all of the `$program->property` values to equal the `$updatedProgram` values?

I have used the `FormType` in the past for a non-api symfony project.
Would it make sense to use it here?